# Is WFC and Android a good combination?

Tags: android, wcf, push

as the title says:

Is it a good idea to use WCF for comminication between server and client? I want to make my own push-service in WCF. It works in C# with a console-application, folowing a tutorial  on YouTube from [PeterTeach](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Dn7ollDhbe4)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, it's a bad idea. Java has big problems interacting with WCF, from my practice.

Using Mono or Xamarin on Android might solve your issue, though (no guarantees).